# Is it possible to lay out 2 buttons vertically on UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, uialertview

I want to create UIAlertView with two buttons. I need to lay out these buttons vertically (my text is too big). Is it possible ?

Screen1

[image]

Screen2

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible by default. The appearance shown in nycynik's answer is what happens when you have more than two buttons.

So, either add another button, or you could look into a third-party solution such as [this library](https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView), although I have not tested it.

Answer (score 8):

There seems to be no SDK support for this behavior. Two buttons in a *UIAlertView* will always be shown in a horizontal layout.

However, it's pretty easy to just subclass *UIAlertView* to get the intended behavior. Let's call the class *VerticalAlertView*.

The following code only works for alert views with two buttons as more than two buttons in a *UIAlertView* will automatically be shown in a vertical layout.

*VerticalAlertView.h* is as simple as this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface VerticalAlertView : UIAlertView
@end
```

*VerticalAlertView.m*:

```
#import "VerticalAlertView.h"

@implementation VerticalAlertView

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    int buttonCount = 0;
    UIButton *button1;
    UIButton *button2;

    // first, iterate over all subviews to find the two buttons;
    // those buttons are actually UIAlertButtons, but this is a subclass of UIButton
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            ++buttonCount;
            if (buttonCount == 1) {
                button1 = (UIButton *)view;
            } else if (buttonCount == 2) {
                button2 = (UIButton *)view;
            }
        }
    }

    // make sure that button1 is as wide as both buttons initially are together
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(button1.frame.origin.x, button1.frame.origin.y, CGRectGetMaxX(button2.frame) - button1.frame.origin.x, button1.frame.size.height);

    // make sure that button2 is moved to the next line,
    // as wide as button1, and set to the same x-position as button1
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(button1.frame.origin.x, CGRectGetMaxY(button1.frame) + 10, button1.frame.size.width, button2.frame.size.height);

    // now increase the height of the (alert) view to make it look nice
    // (I know that magic numbers are not nice...)
    self.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, CGRectGetMaxY(button2.frame) + 15);
}

@end
```

You can now use your class like any other *UIAlertView*:

```
[[[VerticalAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                                  message:@"This is an alert message!" 
                                 delegate:self 
                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                        otherButtonTitles:@"Second Button", nil] autorelease] show];
```

And you will get the following result:

[image]

EDIT:

Using this method is a bit risky (not to say hacky), as Apple might change the implementation of *UIAlertView* at some point, which could break your layout. I just wanted to point out that this would be an easy and fast solution for your problem. As mentioned in the *UIAlertView* reference:

> "The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified."

Comment: This is not working for iOS 7.0 SDK. Will you please suggest something @Flo

Comment: With iOS 7, Apple made it nearly impossible to subclass UIAlertView, but it was never intended to be subclassed anyways. It's not even possible to add custom subviews to the alert anymore, you would have to use the method described here to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21067447/378977. However, unfortunately, I didn't find a solution for two vertically stacked buttons on iOS 7 yet. I think there is no way around creating your own custom class for this. So maybe hava a look at TSAlertView as suggested by [Ian L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596115/ian-l) and make it usable for iOS 7.

Answer (score 3):

**UIAlertview delegates** are **deprecated** in **ios 9.0**

Also when you add more than 2 buttons, they will be vertically assigned by IOS.

you can do with simply UIAlertController

```
UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                  alertControllerWithTitle:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]
                                                            objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]
                                  message:@"share via"
                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    
    UIAlertAction* fbButton = [UIAlertAction
                                actionWithTitle:@"Facebook"
                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                {
                                    // Add your code
                                }];
    UIAlertAction* twitterButton = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:@"Twitter"
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                   {
                                       // Add your code
                                           
                                   }];
    UIAlertAction* watsappButton = [UIAlertAction
                                    actionWithTitle:@"Whatsapp"
                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                    {
                                      // Add your code
                                    }];
    UIAlertAction* emailButton = [UIAlertAction
                                    actionWithTitle:@"Email"
                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                    {
                                       
                                        // Add your code
                                    }];
    UIAlertAction* cancelButton = [UIAlertAction
                                  actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                  {
                                      //Handel no, thanks button
                                      
                                  }];
    
    [alert addAction:fbButton];
    [alert addAction:twitterButton];
    [alert addAction:watsappButton];
    [alert addAction:emailButton];
    [alert addAction:cancelButton];
    
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image: IOS 9 Alert with vertical buttons]

Answer (score 3):

While creating `UIAlertAction`s for `UIAlertController`, just append some white space to titles. Even though they will be trimmed while displaying, iOS lays out buttons vertically.

Tested on iOS 10.3.1 with 4.7" device.
This amount of space is enough even for a button title 1 char length:

`NSString* space = @"                       ";`

Most probably it is OK for 3.5", 4" and 5.5" devices also.

Comment: Note that you should add the spaces at the end of the title. Only they will be trimmed

Answer (score 0):

You could use a placeholder message with many linebreak "\n\n\n", to create the needed space. Than you add a custom button on top of the AlertView. This is of course a hack - not a very solid solution. But there is no straight forward solution for only two buttons to appear on top of each other. With three buttons or more it's the default behaviour anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and it comes by default.
If you add more than 2 Buttons it will automatically take in vertical stack and your buttons will be displayed in vertical position in the alert.
Secondly, if the length of the text you want to display is more then also by default if will take in vertical stack even if the count of button is 2.

Ideally, the alert in the screen has specific height and width beyond it, it will automatically adjust whether to take buttons in horizontal stack or vertical.
Although you can create your custom buttons and alert to display.

Answer (score -1):

You should try:

```
UIAlertView *dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Message"
    delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"  otherButtonTitles:@"Download Next Chapter", nil];
    [dialog show];
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes, here is a page with code & tutorial:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uialertview/

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!"
                                                  message:@"This is your first UIAlertview message."
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Button 1"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Button 2", @"Button 3", nil];
[message show];
```

Comment: The stacked buttons as shown in the linked tutorial are because there are three buttons. Voloda2 has only two buttons, so they are stacked horizontally by default.

Answer (score -3):

**Use this :**

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] 
                       initWithTitle:@"Title"
                       message:@"Two Vertical Button"
                       delegate:nil
                       cancelButtonTitle:@""
                       otherButtonTitles:@"Button 1", @"Button 2",
                       nil]
                     autorelease];
[[alert viewWithTag:1] removeFromSuperview];
[alert show];
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your answer, please include how/why your post will solve the problem.

Comment: This just creates an empty Cancel button... and two other buttons.